# Do I understand MongoDB Realm correctly?

Tags: mongodb, realm, mongodb-atlas, realm-mobile-platform

There are three components:

- Realm Database: Local Storage & Persistence
- Realm Sync: Sync Realm Databases between clients and the Mongo DB Atlas
- Mongo DB Atlas:  A Cloud Database.

You can use each separately or together. So you can

- Just store data locally with Realm Database and not sync it
- Just store data on Mongo DB Atlas without using realm sync, using standard
  queries to access the data.
- Use realm sync to create a synced realm that partitions your mongo db atlas database into a local realm and syncs data between the database and all clients who use it.

Is this all correct?
(Thank you)

Comment: That is correct. Realm Sync is still in beta though. I would not recommend building it into your production systems just yet. The local MongoDB Realm database is a very mature product as is MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: Can you please give me the advice about handling shared data in realm. I mean what should be my partition key in this scenario.

Comment: As I read in the documentation we can only have one partition key at a time for any document.

Comment: Partitions are the worst part of MDB Realm. Yes, you can only have 1 key per document. That means no shared realms between documents. For a Proof of Concept you can use a single partition for all documents, which is a workaround. I would not use MDB Realm for production until they have solved this issue.

Comment: Can you host a realm server locally or do you need Atlas?

Comment: "Can you host a realm server locally or do you need Atlas?" NO - there is no longer a hostable server. There was in the early days, dropped as a product prior to the MongoDB acquisition.

Answer (score 25):

below are some notes for your questions. I'm just getting setup with MongoDB and Realm, myself.

---

### A - Tools

> Realm Database: Local Storage & Persistence

Correct - Client (on-device / local) storage

> Realm Sync: Sync Realm Databases between clients and the Mongo DB Atlas

Somewhat confusingly, there's 2 different implementations of Realm Sync:

1. [Realm Sync](https://docs.realm.io/sync/) - Syncs between clients with Realm (no MongoDB implementation necessary). This uses Realm-run database which costs $30/month
2. [MongoDB Realm with Sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/) - Syncs between Realm clients and MongoDB + Atlas backend which has a 'free forever' sandbox tier.

> Mongo DB Atlas: A Cloud Database.

Correct - A database cluster + UI that is used in most tutorials to setup data models & database configuration.

---

### B - Setups

Based on those understandings, you're correct that these tools can be used differently to have each of these setups. For instance...

> Just store data locally with Realm Database and not sync it

Just normal old [Realm](https://realm.io/docs) for whatever client you need

> Just store data on Mongo DB Atlas without using realm sync, using standard queries to access the data.

Any cloud MongoDB database provider. Atlas is the UI that sets up a database cluster, which you can connect to like any other via MongoDB Compass, etc.

> Use realm sync to create a synced realm that partitions your mongo db atlas database into a local realm and syncs data between the database and all clients who use it.

MongoDB Realm with Sync (#2 above). For this, I've found the [Task Tracker tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/) most helpful.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 7):

MongoDB Realm is basically the cloud application synchronization piece the connects a MongoDB Atlas database to client side realm data. The schema provides the mapping between these two entities. MongoDB Realm also provides an application with a universe of users who can access this cloud data. How users are authenticated into a MongoDB Realm application is determined by the providers the developer has defined.

Comment: does realm only work with atlas? or is it possible to use standalone mongodb community version running on my mac?

Comment: Sync only works with Atlas. Realm prior to acquisition had a different sync server which you will still see referred to in old blog posts, prior to 2019. That server allowed you to run local instances but it was a commercial failure & was never open-sourced.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB Realm Definition: Well if you see in the MongoDB Realm docs you will see -

> MongoDB Realm is a serverless platform and mobile database. MongoDB Stitch and Realm Database are now part of MongoDB Realm.

And also MongoDB Realm is a set of whole Bunch of Features:

- Users & Authentication
- MongoDB Data Access
- Sync
- GraphQL API
- Functions
- Triggers
- Services
- Static Hosting
- Values & Secrets
- Application Management

  So, I think, that's what MongoDB Realm is